# How to catch errors thrown by eval() properly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to make it easier to debug when an exception is thrown by eval().

If I simply do this:

```
let something = 0;
eval("something else");
```

Then everything would crash, and it says:

```
undefined: 1
something else
          ^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'else'
{stacktrace}
```

pointing to whatever the issue was with these `^^^^`, along with the stack trace etc.

However, if I put this in a try/catch like this:

```
try{
    let something = 0;
    eval("something else");
}catch(e){
    console.log(e);
}
```

Then it prints out:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'else'
{stacktrace}
```

without the nice arrows pointing to the problem in the original evaluated string.

How can I catch the error and make it output the exact same thing as it does without catching it? Is it possible?

Comment: Try doing exactly the same thing _except_ create a variable to hold what you are passing to eval instead of passing a string constant. Inside your try-block: `let theCode = "something else"; eval(theCode);`

Comment: @StephenP Putting it in a variable changes absolutely nothing. And the linked answer prints out exactly what I already get in my own try/catch, but less (just the message). Still no arrows pointing to the failing part of the evaluated code. Have also tried printing out its .name and .stack, but there is nothing.
I'm starting to think that the output I'm seeing has nothing to do with the error object, but is part of VSCode debugger or something instead..

Comment: Now I wonder that too — I was putting your original and my suggestion into two Stack Snippets and I get completely different behavior than when I just ran it in a browser console, and running either by putting it in a `<script>` tag in a page gives me the same `SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'else'` you got. 3 different environments, 3 different results. I have _not_ tried VSCode.